# HttpURLConnection method got stuck in current thread;

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

The code below always gets stuck without exception. Which part goes wrong? Should I set connectionTimeOut or readTimeOut?

```
    String result = "";
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try{

        URL realUrl = new URL("https://www.example.com:8089");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)realUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("accept","*/*");
        connection.setRequestProperty("connection","Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.connect();
        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        os.write(params.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while((line = in.readLine())!= null){
            result += line;
        }

    }catch (IOException exio){

    }catch (Exception e){

    }
```

Why does this alway happens?

Comment: 1. With that exception handling you can't possibly know there wasn't an exception. 2. Yes you should set a read timeout. 3. Keep-alive is the default in HTTP 1.1: you don't need to set it. 4. [tag:multithreading] has nothing to do with it whatsoever. 5. `connect()` is redundant.

Comment: On the `OutputStream` you might try a `PrinWriter` set to auto-flush too

Comment: @g00se Or just `flush()` the one he has, but neither is necessary. More likely he needs to *close* it.

Comment: Maybe. It depends on what the server is expecting, I was actually thinking it might be expecting terminal line separator(s)

Comment: @g00se No, it depends on how the `HttpURLConnection's` output stream works. The server is expecting a POST body in accordance with the Content-length header. Nothing startling there.

Comment: afaik, such an output stream would never contribute to a protocol, It would simply accept exactly what's written to it. `flush()` is certainly worth trying first though. I see you've added a point about the content length. I'm not sure if the class will even set that if the header isn't set explicitly, which it isn't

Comment: @g00se I have no idea what you may mean by an output stream contributing to a protocol, but it is certainly possible that either `flush()` or `close() is needed to get the POST parameters to the server. Neither possibility has anything to do with 'what the server is expecting' other than it expecting the POST parameters to be sent, or with using a `PrintWriter`.

Comment: I have to try methods one by one ,hope one of them works!!thanks ,guys!